# SQL table performance - more or fewer tables?

Tags: mysql, performance

While creating a notification system I ran across a question. The community the system is created for is rather big, and I have 2 ideas for my SQL tables:

1. Make one table which includes :

   #### comments table:

   ```
   id(AUTO_INCREMENT) | comment(text) | viewers_id(int) | date(datetime)
   ```

   In this option, the comments are stored with a date and all users that viewed the comment divided with ",".  For example:

   ```
   1| Hi I'm a penguin|1,2,3,4|24.06.1879
   ```

   The system should now use the column `viewers_id` to decide if it should show a notification or not.
2. make two tables like:

   #### comments table:

   ```
   id(AUTO_INCREMENT) | comment(text) | date(datetime)
   ```

   #### viewer table:

   ```
   id(AUTO_INCREMENT) | comment_id | viewers_id(int)
   ```

   example:

   ```
   5|I'm a rock|23.08.1778
   1|5|1,2,3,4
   ```

   In this example we check the `viewers_id` again.

Which of these is likely to have better performance?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505841.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you shouldn't focus that much on optimizing your tables, since its far more rewarding to optimize your application first.
Now to your question:
Increasing the Performance of an SQL Table can be achieved in 2 ways:
1. Normalize as for every SQL Table i would recommend you to normalize it:
[Wikipedia - normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)  2. you can reduce concurrency that means reducing the amount of times when data can't be accessed because it gets changed.
as for your example: if i had to pick one of those i would pick the second option.

Comment: you know nothing, Jon Snow: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc505841.aspx